# Law of total expectation for covariance

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, covariance

Let X and Y be integrable random variables.

We know that  $$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[h(X,Y)] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[h(X,Y)|X]]$$
for any measurable function $h$, positive or integrable on $\mathop{\mathbb{R}}^2$.

So I decided to apply it for the definition of the covariance:

$$cov(X,Y):=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[(X-\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X])(Y-\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Y])] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[(X-\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X])(Y-\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Y])|X]] = 0$$

Can you explain at what point I made a mistake? Why can't the law of total expectation be applied in this case?

Comment: $E[Y-EY|X]$ is not $0$. How do you get the last equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the formula for covariance, $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is a constant value and therefore does *not* behave the way you think when you condition on $X$. Instead, you should think about the formula as being $\mathbb{E}[(X - \mu)(Y - \nu)]$ where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are parameters, and we choose to set $\mu = \mathbb{E}X$ and $\nu = \mathbb{E}Y$ when we do the calculation.

Comment: Thanks!

Just to make sure, would it be correct to do following conditioning:

$$ cov(X,Y):=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[XY]-\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X]\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Y] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[XY|X]]-\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X]\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Y|X]] =  \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Y|X]]-\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X]\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Y|X]]$$ ?

Comment: I had to change a bunch of [X} into [X] to make it parse properly, and if I did that right then the answer is, broadly, yes, although it can help to use notation like $\mathbb{E}[h(X, Y)] = \mathbb{E}_X[\mathbb{E}_{Y|X}[h(X, Y)]]$ to make it easier to see what the expectation is being taken over, and what it is being conditioned on (you could write $\mathbb{E}_{Y}[\cdot|X]$ for $\mathbb{E}_{Y|X}[\cdot]$ as long as it's clear).